# cannot set properly the dict value inside dict

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I cannot set the individual value inside the nested dict as below. Normally I want to set only EntireMaze[(0,1)]['east'] but it sets all 'east' keys. Any idea ?

```
cell = {'east' : 0, 'south' : 0}
EntireMaze = {}

height = 2
width = 3

for row in range(0,height):
    for col in range(0,width):
        EntireMaze[(row,col)] = cell

print EntireMaze
EntireMaze[(0,1)]['east'] = 1
print EntireMaze
```

Output is :

```
>>> 
{(0, 1): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}, (1, 2): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}, (0, 0): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}, (1, 1): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}, (1, 0): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}, (0, 2): {'east': 0, 'south': 0}}

{(0, 1): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}, (1, 2): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}, (0, 0): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}, (1, 1): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}, (1, 0): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}, (0, 2): {'east': 1, 'south': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because every key in `EntireMaze` points to **the same** `cell`. You can either use the code below (with `copy` operation):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import copy

cell = {'east' : 0, 'south' : 0}
EntireMaze = {}

height = 2
width = 3

for row in range(0,height):
    for col in range(0,width):
        EntireMaze[(row,col)] = copy.deepcopy(cell)

print EntireMaze
EntireMaze[(0,1)]['east'] = 1
print EntireMaze
```

or just create each `cell` dict in the loop like that:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

EntireMaze = {}

height = 2
width = 3

for row in range(0,height):
    for col in range(0,width):
        EntireMaze[(row,col)] = {'east' : 0, 'south' : 0}

print EntireMaze
EntireMaze[(0,1)]['east'] = 1
print EntireMaze
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the innermost line if the nested `for` loops:

```
EntireMaze[(row,col)] = cell
```

This sets all values in the `EntireMaze` dictionary to refer to the *same* dictionary -- the one referred to by `cell`.  So when you change one of the entries later, you are actually changing all of them since all of the dictionary keys refer to the same `dict` object.

You need to *copy* the `cell` dictionary if you want the values to be different objects:

```
EntireMaze[(row,col)] = dict(cell)
```

(Note that this will not copy any sub-objects in `cell`, but since you don't have any reference objects in `cell` it doesn't matter in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

As Breet already said:
*You're storing the cell object in each of the values of the dictionary.*
You should copy only dictionary value.

You can do it on this way:

```
EntireMaze[(row,col)] = {'east' : 0, 'south' : 0} #You don't need cell = ...  anymore
```

Or on this:

```
EntireMaze[(row,col)] = {'east' :  cell['east'], 'south' : cell['south']}
```

And also on this way:

```
EntireMaze[(row,col)] = dict(cell)
```

One tip for end: *use `print()`(with **( )**) instead of just print because of Python 3 compatibility.*

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the `cell` object in each of the values of the dictionary. What you need to do is make a copy of it so they are each independent objects.

```
>>> import copy
>>> for row in range(0,height):
...     for col in range(0,width):
...             EntireMaze[(row,col)] = copy.deepcopy(cell)
```